# Displaying different forms in kendo window on click of different buttons

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-window

I have 3 buttons and, on click of every button, totally different content has to be loaded in kendo window. I am doing this in MVC. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your best solution is to create 3 different windows and, in Javascript, when you click on a button, you open the window and close others.

Or, you can also create only one window and load it's content dynamically when a button is clicked. But you have to deal with Kendo Window API.

If you want to reload the content of a window, see [this link](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window#methods-refresh).

Comment: that's what i want to know if i want load content dynamically what are those methods in Kedo API which i can use. Can i get some example related to that ?